# Can Webpack Dev server create files in my project root?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an project set up and running with `Webpack 5.28.0` and `webpack-dev-server 4.11.1`

Its all working nicely but I would like to be able to have the dev server write some files back to my project root. These are debug/log files that I'd like to save as JSON.
I'd also like this to be automatic, I don't want to have to click anything or trigger the action manually.

So the ideal flow would be that I run `npm start`, my build kicks off in a browser, the page generates a load of log data and this is then written back to my project root. Either using some browser function or calling back to Node script in my build.

Is this possible with dev-server?

Comment: Where does the data come from for these JSON files?

Comment: _"the page generates"... do you mean the web page? As in the data comes from code running in the browser?

Comment: @Phil The data is just a string effectively, generated by the front end code. In the past I've been simply logging it to the console but as it gets more complex I'd like to write it back to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup the [dev-server middleware](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserversetupmiddlewares) to add an API endpoint to accept data and write it to your filesystem

```js
// webpack.config.js

const { writeFile } = require("node:fs/promises");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

module.exports = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
      devServer.app?.post(
        "/__log",
        bodyParser.json(),
        async (req, res, next) => {
          try {
            await writeFile(
              "debug-log.json",
              JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2)
            );
            res.sendStatus(202);
          } catch (err) {
            next(err);
          }
        }
      );
      return middlewares;
    },
  },
};
```

Then your front-end app needs only to construct the payload and POST it to the dev-server

```js
const debugData = { /* ... */ };
fetch("/__log", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(debugData),
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
});
```

Comment: This sounds very promising indeed. I've been shifted to another job temporarily but I will try this soon and accept it (hopefully)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, so thanks. Its opened up more questions than it answered but that is often the way with these things. Thanks again